# How do generic types work for getters and setters?

Tags: java, generics, setter, getter

I am trying to create getters and setters for a 2D grid while using generic types, but I'm somewhat confused in how to treat them differently as I'm getting errors. Here are the methods with some javadoc on what they should be doing.

```
public class IntGrid2D<T> implements IIntGrid2D{
private IIntPoint2D p;
private T v;
 /**
 * Sets the value at a point on the grid, replacing the previous value if any.
 * @param p The coordinate to set the value of
 * @param v The value to set at the coordinate
 * @throws OffGridException if p is outside the grid
 */
public void setPoint(IIntPoint2D p, T v) throws OffGridException{
    this.p = p;
    this.v = T;

}


/**
 * Gets the value at a point on the grid
 * @param p The coordinate to get the value of
 * @return the stored value
 * @throws OffGridException if p is outside the grid
 */
public T getPoint(IIntPoint2D p) throws OffGridException{
    return p;
}
/**
 * Gets the coordinate for the upper left most location
 * @return an IIntPoint that is the coordinate of the upper left corner
 */
public IIntPoint2D getUpperLeftCorner(){
}
/**
 * Gets the coordinate for the lower right most location
 * @return an IIntPoint that is the lower right corner
 */
public IIntPoint2D getLowerRightCorner(){
}
}
```

Comment: Show the error message(s) (as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: `p` is not always `t` in your `getPoint` method.

Comment: If you use `point` and `value` as your variable names, and V as the type of the value, maybe you'd notice that you're trying to return a point from a method whose return type is V, the type of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Change `getPoint` to this:

```
public T getPoint(IIntPoint2D p) throws OffGridException{
    return v;
}
```

Comment: You should probably get rid of the parameter.

Comment: @shmosel the argument is necessary, according to the javadoc of the class and of the method. But just having a single v field is nonsensical, and returning it from that method, is nonsensical. And the method should really be renamed getValue(), or getValueAt(). Correct naming is probably the biggest problem in the posted code.